# Self Upgrade to rollback if .NET 4 not installed using wyBuild

Tags: .net, wybuild

I am using wyBuild in one of the .net projects to create the .exe file. Currently, it is in .net 3.5 frameworks.

I want to upgrade my application to .Net framework 4 client profile.

How I can say to wyBuild to upgrade my application version to new version if the machine has.Net framework 4 client profile installed or rollback to the previous version which was working with .net 3.5 frameworks if it does not have .net 4 client profile framework?

I am not sure how can I do this using wyBuild? Please provide info anyone has any info?

Comment: Even if you succeed, wouldn't this make it an unpleasant experience for the user of your software? Constantly trying to upgrade only to roll it back? I would consider this two completely different lines of releases for your program and start over with the .NET 4+ version.

Comment: We have different clients who use our application. only a few clients machines are older. Usually, we will not release a new release to all of our customers as it would be difficult given the size. Please let me know how I can do this if there is any possibility?